# Mysql Query - Copy resultset from one database to another

Tags: mysql

I have a large db that I am chopping into smaller databases based on time intervals.  This will reduce query time dramatically.  In a query can I copy a resultset from one database to another with an identical schema?

Basically a select followed by an update conducted in the same code block?

Thanks,

slothishtype

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copying data from one database into another should be almost as simple as @slotishtype describes except you'll need to qualify it with the OTHER database you want it replicated into.

```
create table OtherDatabase.Student Select * from FirstDatabase.student
```

However, as you mention about copying same schema, that is something else.  If you want all your R/I rules, triggers, etc, you may have to dump the database schema from your first (where it has all the create tables, indexes, etc) and run in a new database.  However, that might post an issue where you have auto-incrementing columns.  You can't write to a read-only auto-increment column -- the database controls that.  However, if such case existed, you would have to just make those columns as integer datatypes (or similar) and do a

```
insert into OtherDatabase.Student ( field1, field2, etc )
   select field1, field2, etc from FirstDatabase.student
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is not necessary to add it to a new database, this will do fine:

CREATE TABLE student1 SELECT * FROM student

**EDIT:** for the record: This will not coopy over indices etc.

This, however, will:

CREATE TABLE student_new LIKE student;
INSERT recipes_new SELECT * FROM student;

slotishtype